# Get the value of runtime created input text field and put it as runtime created img src then display that image

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ShoppingCart.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="UpperDiv">

        </div>
        <div id="MiddleDiv">
        <div class="AdminPage" id="PartOne">
            <div>
                <table id="itemsTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Image</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Stock</td>
                            <td>Actions</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>    
                </table>

                <div><img id="addTo" src="plus.png" alt="addTo" width="40" height="40"/></div>    
            </div>
            <div class="AdminPage" id="PartTwo">
                    Name:<input type="text" name="Name" class="AdminTxt"/>
                    Image path:<input type="text" name="Image" class="AdminTxt"/>
                    Unit price:<input type="text" name="Price" class="AdminTxt"/>
                    Stock:<input type="text" name="Stock" class="AdminTxt"/>
                    <button id="AddProduct">Add Product</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="PageTwo" id="ClientPage"></div>
            <div class="PageThree" id="CheckOutPage"></div>    
        </div>
        <div id="LeftDiv">
            <button id="AdminPanel">Admin Panel</button>
            <button id="Client">Client</button>
            <button id="Checkout">Checkout</button>
        </div>

        <script src="ShoppingCart.js"></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){         
    $("#AdminPage").on("click",function(){
        $("#ClientPage").hide();
        $("#CheckOutPage").hide();
        $("#PartTwo").hide();
        $("#PartOne").show();
    });

    $("#addTo").on("click",function(){
        $("#PartTwo").css({"display":"inline-block"});
    });       

    $("#AddProduct").on("click",function(){
        ////// read the value each time the add product clicked
        var textName=$(".AdminTxt").eq(0).val();
        var imagePath=$(".AdminTxt").eq(1).val();
        var unitPrice=$(".AdminTxt").eq(2).val();
        var stock=$(".AdminTxt").eq(3).val();
        /// put the values inside the html
        var html='<tr class="tableRows">' +
            '<td id="imgCol" class="Cols"><img id="Img" src="'+imagePath+'" alt="" width="100px" height="100px"/></td>' +
            '<td id="nameCol" class="Cols">'+textName+'</td>' +
            '<td id="priceCol" class="Cols">'+unitPrice+'</td>' +
            '<td id="stockCol" class="Cols">'+stock+'</td>' +
            '<td id="ActionsCol" class="ColsNedit"><img src="Edit-icon.png" id="editIc" alt="edit" width="50px" height="50px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            '<img src="delete.png" id="delIc" alt="delete" width="50" height="50"></td>' +
            '</tr>';
        $("#itemsTable").append(html);
        //console.log("add")
        //alert(textName);
        $("#PartTwo").css({"display":"none"});   ////make the form disapear
        $(".AdminTxt").val("");
        });

     $("#itemsTable").delegate("#delIc","click",function(){
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
     });

     var flag=0;
     $("#itemsTable").delegate("#editIc","click",function(){
        //$("#PartTwo").show();
        var tds=$(this).closest("tr").find("td").filter(".Cols");
        var Imgsrc;
        var newsrc;
        if(flag==0) {
            tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
            var image=$(this).closest("tr").find("td").children(0);
            var imgsrc=image.attr("src");
            //var imgsrc=$(this).imagePath;   
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").children().eq(0).replaceWith("<input id='Imgsrc' type='text' value="+imgsrc+"/>");
            //$(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").children().eq(0).attr("value");

            flag = 1;
        }
        else if(flag==1){
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);    

                newsrc = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").children().eq(0).attr("value");
                alert(newsrc);
                $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").children().eq(0).replaceWith("<img id='newSrc' src=" + newsrc + " width='100px' height='100px'/>");       
        }    
    });      
});
```

> the edit button will make the table rows editable

The question is

I want to replace an image tag with input text tag with its value is the src of the image then when I clicked on the edit icon again the value of the input text field will be the newsrc of the image.

The problem is the image src still the old one after editing

How could I do that ??

Note that all of these elements created at the runtime

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting the value of `input` with `attr('value')`. You should use `val()` instead, because `attr('value')` always return the first value.
Try like following. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
var flag = 0;
$("#itemsTable").delegate("#editIc", "click", function () {
    var tds = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").filter(".Cols");

    if (flag == 0) {
       tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
       var image = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first > img");
       var imgsrc = image.attr("src");
       image.replaceWith("<input id='Imgsrc' type='text' value=" + imgsrc + " />");

       flag = 1;
    }
    else if (flag == 1) {
       tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
       var text = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first > input");
       var newsrc = text.val();
       text.replaceWith("<img id='newSrc' src=" + newsrc + " width='100px' height='100px' />");

       flag = 0;
    }
});
```